# MySQL -- deleting or indexing?

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

I need some advice from you.
There is some huge table(innodb), with ~600kk(600 millions) rows. MySQL version is 5.5. DB in live/production system.
Structure example:

```
CREATE TABLE `rows` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `str_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `file_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `upload_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `acticity_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `MSGID_INDEX` (`str_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

All going well for this time, but we need to delete trash rows from table, delete clause is:

```
WHERE file_id = 0 AND activity_date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Table full of trash rows ~50-60%(300-400kk). So we need to delete many rows, logical way is trying to delete with chunks, but the problem is that we have not index on(file_id, activity_date), so delete takes too much time. 
For example(try with 1k up to 100k, optimal(by time) is 100k):

```
DELETE from rows WHERE file_id = 0 AND activity_date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) LIMIT 100000;
```

executing ~5-6 min, it takes too long. 
Maybe we need to add index(file_id, activity_date) to table(we have 5.5 mysql version) and then try to delete, but it is production DB, so adding index can cause some locks, another way is continue deleting rows step by step ?
Anyway we need to add index, but would be better if we do it after cleaning trash from DB.
Any advice ?

**UPD**

Seems to be I find satisfied solution(I use 5k chunk, but it is not guarantee that this 5k will be deleted from DB, it is optimal variant for my db, and it takes few seconds) relative to my task, use id field like rows reducer. Thank you for your advice! Approach, simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "exit" INT
COUNTER=1
LIMIT=5000
START=1300000000
while :
do
        date1=$(date +"%s")
        Q="DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE id > $(($START + $LIMIT)) AND id < $(($START + 2*$LIMIT)) AND YOUR_CLAUSE LIMIT $LIMIT;"
        mysql -D DB_NAME -uroot -p"PASS" -e "$Q"
        date2=$(date +"%s")
        diff=$(($date2-$date1))
        echo "chunk($Q) deleted -- $COUNTER, $(($diff / 60)) minutes and $(($diff % 60)) seconds elapsed."
        COUNTER=$[$COUNTER +1]
        START=$(($START + $LIMIT))
        #sleep 1
done
```

Thank you!

Comment: This question is beyond my understanding, but what comes to mind is making a duplicate database with an indexed column. If you need to, write live transactions to both databases, and then transition solely to the new one when you are convinced they are in sync.

Comment: If it matches 50-60% - the index will not be used anyway. Just delete in smaller chunks more frequently.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider [partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/partitioning.html) your table?

Answer (score 2):

`LIMIT 100000` is too much.  1000 should suffice.

If `id` and `activity_date` go hand in hand, then the query should work ok until you get to the last one.  At that point it will scan the whole table and be a nuisance.

If they don't go hand in hand, the DELETEs will get slower and slower as it has to step over 'new' rows with 'old' ids.

Better would be to chunk the table based on `id`.  I go into detail on that in [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig).

Note that it uses LIMIT 1000,1 to find how far to reach -- It will touch 1000 rows, then delete *up to* 1000 rows.  This keeps the effort bounded always.

Yes, it will take "days" to finish.  At that point, you may as well start over!

*If you did not have the `file_id=0` test*:

Even better (for the future) would be to have the table be `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(activitydate))`.  Then `DROP PARTITION` will be instantaneous.  I go into the details, including sample code, in [another blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

Even better (perhaps) would be to convert to PARTITIONing *now*, by copying over *just* the "new" data.  This *one time* process would go something like

- `CREATE TABLE new (...) PARTITION BY ...;`
- `INSERT INTO new SELECT * FROM rows WHERE activitydate > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY;`
- `RENAME TABLE rows TO old, new TO rows;`
- `DROP TABLE old;`

That will be the fastest way to get the entire task done.  Future DELETEs will be done by `DROP PARTITION`, which is instantaneous.  But...  The `INSERT...SELECT` will take a long time, and you should not be writing to `rows` while that is going on.

So, you choose:

- Chunking DELETE (no downtime) today and tomorrow and...; or
- Take some downtime *once* to switch to PARTITION and get rid of the old data.

Caveats:  `FOREIGN KEYS` and some `UNIQUE` constraints do not work with `PARTITION`.

Comment: "1000 should suffice." --- keeping in mind you need to delete 300M records - it means you need to run it 300k times. Which is 4 days if you run it every second. Are you still sure it's a good idea to stress the DB for 4 complete days?

Comment: The partition solution will not work either, since you don't delete all the data for the day, but only the ones with `file_id = 0`. Which again cannot be optimized by index hence will cause a full scan. Keeping my 2 notes in mind: do you still think your suggestion is any kind better than what OP already has?

Comment: "Stress the DB for 4 complete days" -- The DB will happily do penance for your sin of not thinking about deletion.  ;)

Comment: Oops, I missed the file_id test.  That implies that the chunked delete while walking through via `id` may be the best plan.